# Suppress vertical space after `\printindex`

Tags: spacing, indexing

In `\documentclass{book}`, `\printindex` shunts the first two columns of my index down the page leaving white space that I don't need.  What is the name of this space so that I can reset it to zero?

In reference to the picture below: The aim is to have *’ábé* (top of left column, left page) and *’əuk’ə́mi* (top of right column, left page) align horizontally with *hunav'á* and *kamentʃú* (top of left and right columns, right page).

[image]

Comment: please tell us at least what document class you're using, and what indexing package(s).  (different document classes and indexing packages behave in different ways.)  a minimum example would be even better, but may be rather complicated to construct.  `\printindex` *usually* begins with a `\chapter*` heading, which would explain the sink at the top of the first page, but the presence of a running head there means that the defaults have already been "adjusted".

Comment: It's a `book` (question edited).  The vertical skip is, indeed, identical to that following a chapter title.

Comment: Following on from @barbarabeeton's comment, insert `\chapter*{\indexname}` before `\printindex`. If it produces a normal unnumbered chapter, then the `theindex` environment has been modified, otherwise `\@schapter` (`\chapter*`) has been modified. Once you've determine which of these has happened, you then need a systematic approach to determine which package has altered the definition.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a `\renewcommand{\indexname}{}` somewhere in the preamble, which removes the chapter heading but still leaves all the chapter heading construction (spacing and such).

Comment: @Werner That was my first thought, but `\chapter` usually issues `\thispagestyle{plain}` which doesn't seem to have happened given that the page header showing.

Comment: Thanks.  The discussion above was enough to put me in the right direction.  I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Barbara Beeton's tip and Nicola Talbot's comment, I added this directly before `\printindex`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[runin]{}{}{}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{0pt}
```

using `titlesec.sty`.  Hope this helps anyone else with similar queries.